# Principal series representations for complex groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a complex semisimple group.
In Bernstein-Gelfand, "Tensor products of finite and infinite dimensional representations of semisimple Lie algebras" (http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1980__41_2_245_0.pdf), they define a *principal series* representation of $G$ by taking the hom-space between a Verma and a dual Verma.

Now suppose we view $G$ as real. Does this coincide with the notion of *principal series* representation for *real reductive groups*? And what about the relation with Langlands standard module for real reductive groups?